# Manifest has to have a label

Tags: android

When I tried to publish my Android app (for Android 2.1) on http://slideme.org I got an error which says Manifest has to have label, but I have labels every where where I can put them.

So if someone can point me out where is problem please respond.

Here is my manifest.

```xml
<manifest package="com.jandans.silencer"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:sharedUserLabel="@string/nosaukums">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER" />
    
    <application  android:label="Silent Mode" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode" 
       >
        
       <activity android:name=".Info"
                android:label="Silent mode">
                <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <receiver android:name=".widgetprow"
                android:label="Silent Mode"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode">                            
                <intent-filter>
                    <action
               android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />  
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data
                                         android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                        android:resource="@xml/hey" />         
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".widgetprow$ToggleService" android:label="Silent Mode"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: And when you contacted slideme.org tech support, what did they tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the start tag `<application` contains the attribute android:icon that references to a resource prefixed with '@android:'. This breaks apk parser, thus the reason why you get the 'label' error when you attempt to upload your app.

Your `<application` start tag looks like this:

```
<application  android:label="Silent Mode"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode">
```

It should be fixed by replacing the reference prefix from '@android:drawable:" to "@drawable" (see below)

```
<application  android:label="Silent Mode" android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Might be tangentially related but in general its frowned upon using literal strings for android:label in application, activity, service, etc. It is allowed, however, but may throw warnings as they would rather you use something like "@string/*KEY*" for a resource under /res/values/*SOMEFILE*.xml where *SOMEFILE* is an xml file with the resources root tag and has a string specified for *KEY*. Typically *SOMEFILE* in this instance is strings.xml.

Main reason for this is for [localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) so you can provide a different name for say French users by simply providing a file with the same name but in /res/values-fr directory.